# Input numbers from file

Tags: input

I have numbers I need to put into my text in latex. The only possibility I know is using `\input`. So I put every single number in its own file. E.g. the file `foo.dat` contains `6.062843465325870040e-01` (I checked for trailing white spaces).

The first problem that appears is, that latex apparently puts a space after `\input`. So `My number is \input{foo.dat}.` yields

```
My number is 6.062843465325870040e-01 .
```

Note the unwanted space before the dot `.`.

---

The next problem is, that I obviously want properly formatted numbers. So I use `siunits`' `\num`. But `\num{\input{foo.dat}}` yields an error.

How can I fix this, or are there better solutions (without generating the properly formatted latex code as a file).

---

I considered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29078107/insert-values-from-a-file-in-a-latex-document for my solution so far.

Comment: do you really need to just have one number per file?

Comment: No, preferable I would like to save a dictionary with key - number pairs.  Saving one number per file is just a workaround to use Latex as I know it. (I am aware of solutions like using Python from within Latex. At the moment I don't have time to investigate these things, so I prefer plain Latex.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\unskip` is your friend.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.dat}
  6.062843465325870040e-01
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
My number is
  \textit{\input{foo.dat}\unskip}.
\end{document}
```

For usage with `siunitx` you might want to use the `catchfile` package:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.dat}
  6.062843465325870040e-01
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\begin{document}
My number is
  \CatchFileDef{\foonum}{foo.dat}{}%
  \num\foonum.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If you have to do this very often it might be useful to wrap this process into a macro.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.dat}
  6.062843465325870040e-01
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand*\OutputFileNum[2][\num]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\tempnum}{#2}{}%
  #1{\tempnum}%
}

\begin{document}
My number is \OutputFileNum{foo.dat}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks this answer works. I am a bit annoyed that I need to save the number to a variable first and then use the variable. I find this very ugly as I use the number only once. But I as long as I can hide it behind an command it is at least a very convenient workaround.

Comment: @egreg What a stupendous oversight of mine... Thanks!

Comment: @DerWeh a slight caveat of the input implementation, but(!) with the variable approach the spacing problem disappears ;)

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

> I have numbers I need to put into my text in latex. The only possibility I know is using `\input`. So I put every single number in its own file.

Another solution would consist of defining macros, named (say) `\numA`, `\numB`, etc, as follows

```
\newcommand\numA{6.062843465325870040e-01}
\newcommand\numB{3.141592653589793238e-00}
```

in the preamble and to use them in the body of the text as follows:

```
My first number is \numA.
```

If you want to apply some formatting, e.g., employ "thousands separators", load the `siunitx` package and write

```
My second number is \num{\numB}.
```

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for '\num' macro
\newcommand\numA{6.062843465325870040e-01}
\newcommand\numB{3.141592653589793238}
\begin{document}
My first number is \numA.

My second number is \num{\numB}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: While this indeed is a solution, it doesn't match my requirements. The numbers in the files will regularly change, so I can't hard-code them in my latex code. (Unless I let my code producing the numbers also change my Latex files. But I strictly refuse this workflow!) So the solution would be to actually put the latex markup `\newcommand....` into the files. Again I would just consider it as an ugly hack.

Answer (score 0):

A easy way to store numbers (as many as you want in a single file) and retrieve single numbers can be done with LaTeX + R integration via `knitr`. Better, you can do any math with these numbers in the same document.  If you do not know what on earth I'm talking about, just install [Rstudio](https://www.rstudio.com/) and [R](https://www.r-project.org/), save the both files below in the same testing directory, open `test.Rnw` with Rstudio and click on the "Compile PDF".

test.dat

```
3.037494573458934585e-04
6.062843465325870040e-01
9.331454567567567675e-05
```

test.Rnw

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<loaddata,echo=F,comment="">>=
mynumbers <-read.csv(file="test.dat",header=F)
x <- formatC(mynumbers$V1[2], format = "e", digits = 18)
@
My first  number is \Sexpr{mynumbers$V1[1]}.\par
My second number is \Sexpr{mynumbers$V1[2]}.\par 
My third  number is \Sexpr{mynumbers$V1[3]}.\par 
\bigskip
<<changeoptions,echo=F>>=
options(scipen=2,digits=19)
@
My second number roughly is \Sexpr{round(mynumbers$V1[2],2)}, 
more precisely  \Sexpr{round(mynumbers$V1[2],5)}.\par
My second number is \Sexpr{mynumbers$V1[2]}.\par
My second number is \Sexpr{x}.\par 
\end{document}
```

Result:

> [image: MWE]